# How to make multiple graphs with varying x-axis?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot multiple graphs in the same y-axis, but the x-axis is a bit tricky for me:

Assuming it goes from `0` to `a`, increasing by one, it needs to have an overall of `a-1` different intervals.

Each one of them should finish at `a`, but it also has to have a different initialisation point. Only the first starts at `0`, while each next one, starts by the previous plus one, as in the shape below. The two dashed lines, I used to visualise my thoughts as clear as I could, are not necessary.

I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicate your original interval `0 ... a` `a` times (from my understanding, you'll have `a` intervals, not `a-1`), such that you get a matrix `X` of size `[a x a+1]`. Set the lower left triangle of `X` to `NaN`, so that the rows now represent your (shortening) intervals. Do your calculations on `X`. Pay attention, these have to support/neglect `NaN` values properly.

After that, you need to adjust the values in `X` properly, so that the intervals are plotted subsequently. Basically, we add some fixed value to each row.

Last, we need the proper [`xticks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html) and [`xticklabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html). Therefore, we extract all values from `X` and the modified `X` and get rid of the `NaN` values.

Here's a complete code snippet:

```matlab
% Parameter
a = 7;

% Initialize intervals
X = repmat(0:a, a, 1);
X = X .* (ones(size(X)) + tril(nan(size(X)), -1));

% Calculation on these intervals; attention: there are NaN in X
Y = sin(X / a * 2 * pi);

% Modify X for plotting
X_plot = X;
X_plot(2:end, :) = X_plot(2:end, :) + cumsum(a:-1:2).';

% Get xticks
xt = X_plot.';
xt = xt(:);
xt(isnan(xt)) = [];

% Get xticklabels
xtl = X.';
xtl = xtl(:);
xtl(isnan(xtl)) = [];

% Plot
plot(X_plot.', Y.');
xticks(xt);
xticklabels(xtl);
```

The output (Octave 5.1.0, also tested with MATLAB Online) looks like this:

[image: Output]

If you only want for example the start and end of each interval, you must further pre-process `xt` and `xtl`.

Hope that helps!